# C# login with ms-acess database, login information taken from 3 tables

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am trying to make my login form use the usernames and passwords from three different tables because I need that distinction to be made later on in my project. I have made a Union query in Access to help me read the information and it works in Access but not when I try to use it in my OleDbCommand. It's giving me this error: 
'The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect.' 
This is the Access query:

```
SELECT ASISTENTI.Nume_Utilizator AS Nume_Utilizator, ASISTENTI.Parola AS Parola
FROM ASISTENTI 
UNION ALL
SELECT MEDICI.Nume_Utilizator AS Nume_Utilizator, MEDICI.Parola AS Parola
FROM MEDICI
UNION ALL SELECT PACIENTI.Nume_utilizator AS Nume_Utilizator, PACIENTI.Parola AS Parola
FROM PACIENTI;
```

This is the C# code:
            OleDbCommand comanda = new OleDbCommand();
            comanda.Connection = conexiune;

```
        comanda.CommandText = "SELECT ASISTENTI.Nume_Utilizator AS Nume_Utilizator, ASISTENTI.Parola AS Parola FROM ASISTENTI UNION ALL SELECT MEDICI.Nume_Utilizator AS Nume_Utilizator, MEDICI.Parola AS ParolaFROM MEDICI UNION ALL SELECT PACIENTI.Nume_utilizator AS Nume_Utilizator, PACIENTI.Parola AS Parola FROM PACIENTI;";
        OleDbDataReader reader = comanda.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: You don't have a space before the FROM word: `MEDICI.Parola AS ParolaFROM MEDICI`

Comment: that's embarrassing, thank you!